# Convert C++ std::chrono::duration_cast<std::chrono::milliseconds> to PHP DateTime

Tags: php, c++, datetime

I´m writing an application composed of a C++ process that acquires data and stores it in a Sqlite3 database, and a PHP Web application to analyze that data.

Some collected data generates `DateTime` formats, that are stored on a `INTEGER` type field on Sqlite3.

At the C++ side, the following piece of code is used to generate the timestamps (in milliseconds precision, as I´m dealing with a real time system):

```
int64_t convertTimePointToInt64(const std::chrono::time_point<std::chrono::system_clock> &time)
{
    auto count = time.time_since_epoch();
    auto value = std::chrono::duration_cast<std::chrono::milliseconds>(count);

    return value.count();
}

std::chrono::time_point<std::chrono::system_clock> dt = std::chrono::system_clock::now();
auto valueToStore = convertTimePointToInt64(dt);
```

The `valueToStore` is then INSERT´ed on Sqlite using SQL (`INTEGER` type).

My problem is when I try to read it on the Web application. I´m using the following PHP code, where `$t` is the database INTEGER value:

```
$micro = sprintf("%06d",($t - floor($t)) * 1000000);
$d = new \DateTime( date('Y-m-d H:i:s.'.$micro, $t) );
$a = $d->format("Y-m-d H:i:s.u");
```

I´m getting stange values (1031 in year, for example) that indicates the PHP logic is messy.

The C++ code is running very fine (I can store and retrive timestamps and convert it to/back to `std::string`). I need to fix my PHP code to show the data correctly.

Help appreciated.

Comment: If the database contains 1441222475, you didn't get the miliseconds. That looks about right for a conventional POSIX timestamp, so miliseconds should require an extra three digits.

Comment: Correct. Now I noticed that this was saved by the PHP side. I will drop it from the post, but the problem remains the same...

Comment: If I understand this correctly, your value of $t is in milliseconds, then converting it to seconds involves dividing by a million, not multiplying. And if $t is in seconds, nothing needs to be done. PHP, I'm sure, is expecting to get the number of seconds since epoch, not the number of milliseconds.

Comment: Sam, but if I divide it will truncate the milliseconds, or not ? I´m trying to convert from millisenconds to nanoseconds, something that PHP seens to support...